# Помогите, не могу разобраться. Начинающий)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не знаю как правильно написать код, чтобы допустим выводились книги, для одной это нормально, а если 100(книг) то как?

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author

    def prnt(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.author)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    book = Book('Золотая рыбка', 'А.С.Пушкин')
    print(book.prnt())

    book1 = Book('Кавкзаский пленник', 'А.С.Пушкин')
    print(book1.prnt())
```

Comment: а откуда вы берете названия книг и их авторов?

Comment: Хранить книги в списке и выводить из списка. `books = []` + `books.append(Book('Золотая рыбка', 'А.С.Пушкин'))` + `for book in books: print(book.prnt())`

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N   к сожалению ошибся, мне стыдно

Comment: @An Mal,за что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author

        self.info = '%s %s' % (self.name, self.author)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    library = [('Золотая рыбка', 'А.С.Пушкин',), ('Кавкзаский пленник', 'А.С.Пушкин',)]

    for book in library:
        item = Book(*book)
        print(item.info)
```